# Bonobo GIT Server Sending an Email on Check In

Tags: git, hook, bonobo

Can someone share a hook template that works in the Bonobo Server when a change/add is posted?

I have been trying to find an example of how to set up the Bonobo GIT Server to send an email whenever it receives a push and haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.